# Getting started with Serilog in xamarin project

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to set up a logging system for a xamarin project and I've the following code

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Debug()
               .WriteTo.Console()
               .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("Hello, world!");

            int a = 10, b = 0;
            try
            {
                Log.Debug("Dividing {A} by {B}", a, b);
                Console.WriteLine(a / b);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "Something went wrong");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
```

this I wrote in App constructor to test it first but it throws a runtime error that says

**System.PlatformNotSupportedException:** 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

If i remove the .WriteTo.Console() it works so I assume that I have to configure a console or something like that?

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin

Answer (score 0):

The `Serilog.Sinks.Console` sink you are using is not available on your platform. Instead, like Jason suggests in the comments you will need to use a different sink.

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you may want to sink into a

- File
- Debug output
- Device log

Sinks exist for all of these scenarios and there are also sinks for more complicated scenarios where you want to stream your log to an external service such as Elastic Search or some other service.

However, Console, is not available on *all* platforms and you should select a more appropriate sink(s).

Answer (score 0):

### Dependencies

1. Install `Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin` from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin) ([GitHub](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-xamarin))
2. Install `IOFlextils` from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IOFlextils)

### Configure Serilog in Native Projects

#### Xamarin.IOS

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.NSLog()
.CreateLogger();
```

#### Xamarin.Android

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.AndroidLog()
.Enrich.WithProperty(Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, "MyCustomTag") //Sets the Tag field.
.CreateLogger();
```

### Building

So lets say you want to implement something that will log to the native log console as well as to a sqlite db. You may want remote access to your logs through a backgroud worker of sorts.

##### Constants.cs

```
public static class Constants
{
    private const string LogDatabaseFileName = "logs.db3";

    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        // create the database if it doesn't exist
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    public static string LogDatabasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            return Path.Combine(basePath, LogDatabaseFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Log.cs

```
public class Log : BaseSyncEntity<long>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public string Level { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public string Properties { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    public string RenderedMessage { get; set; }
}
```

#### LogDatabase.cs

```
public class LogDatabase
{
    private static readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> LazyInitializer =
        new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() => new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.LogDatabasePath, Constants.Flags));

    private static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database => LazyInitializer.Value;

    private static bool _initialized = false;

    private Type[] _tables =
    {
        typeof(Log),
    };

    public LogDatabase()
    {
        InitializeAsync().SafeFireAndForget(false);
    }

    async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        if (!_initialized)
            if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => this._tables.Any(t => m.MappedType.Name == nameof(t))))
            {
                foreach (var t in this._tables) await Database.CreateTableAsync(t, CreateFlags.None);
                _initialized = true;
            }
    }

    #region Log

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    /// <param name="limit"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<Log[]> GetLogsAsync(EntityState state, int limit = 10)
    {
        return await Database.Table<Log>().Where(x => x.State == state)
            .Take(limit)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .ToArrayAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Documentation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="log"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<int> SaveAsync(Log log)
    {
        return log.Id <= 0 ? Database.InsertAsync(log) : Database.UpdateAsync(log);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

#### Xamarin.Android MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.Work;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Content;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using Serilog;

namespace GenericApp.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "Generic App", 
          Icon = "@mipmap/icon", 
          Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize,
          WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    private DataWedgeReceiver _dataWedge;
    private App _app;
    /// <summary>
    /// Lifecycle method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="savedInstanceState"></param>
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        _app = new App();
        LoadApplication(_app);
        DependencyService.Register<IConnection, ConnectionService>();

        #region Periodic Work Requests

        WorkManager.GetInstance(this).CancelAllWork();

        #endregion

        App.IntentScanningAvailable = IsAppInstalled("com.symbol.datawedge");

        if (App.IntentScanningAvailable)
        {
            _dataWedge = new DataWedgeReceiver();
            _dataWedge.ScanReceived += (sender, data) =>
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send(_app, "com.sw.mobile.BARCODE_SCAN", data);
            };
        }
        
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.AndroidLog()
            .WriteTo.SQLiteNetPcl(Constants.LogDatabasePath, storeTimestampInUtc: true, batchSize:1)
            .Enrich.WithProperty(App.KeyAppId, App.AppId)
            .Enrich.WithProperty(App.KeyAppVersion, App.AppVersion)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    bool IsAppInstalled(string packageName)
    {
        try
        {
            PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(packageName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
            return true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Log.Error(nameof(MainActivity), ex, ex.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(nameof(MainActivity), e.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }

    PeriodicWorkRequest GetWorkRequest<T>(string tag, int minutes) where T : Worker
    {
        return PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<T>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes)).AddTag(tag).Build();
    }

    void RegisterWorkerSubscription<T>(Type type, string message, string tag) 
        where T : BaseWorker
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<T>(this, message, (page) =>
        {
            var request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(type)
                .AddTag(tag)
                .SetInputData(new AndroidX.Work.Data.Builder().PutString("arg_msg", message).Build())
                .Build();
            WorkManager.GetInstance(this).BeginUniqueWork(tag, ExistingWorkPolicy.Keep, request).Enqueue();
        });
    }

    void RegisterSubscription<T>(Type type, string message, string tag) 
        where T : BaseViewModel
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<T>(this, message, (page) =>
        {
            var request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(type)
                .AddTag(tag)
                .SetInputData(new AndroidX.Work.Data.Builder().PutString("arg_msg", message).Build())
                .Build();
            WorkManager.GetInstance(this).BeginUniqueWork(tag, ExistingWorkPolicy.Keep, request).Enqueue();
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Documentation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestCode"></param>
    /// <param name="permissions"></param>
    /// <param name="grantResults"></param>
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        if (App.IntentScanningAvailable && _dataWedge != null)
        {
            var filter = new IntentFilter(DataWedgeReceiver.IntentAction);
            filter.AddCategory(DataWedgeReceiver.IntentCategory);
            Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(_dataWedge, filter);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        if(App.IntentScanningAvailable && _dataWedge != null)
            Android.App.Application.Context.UnregisterReceiver(_dataWedge);
        
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serilog.Sinks.Console with Xamarin Android and Xamarin IOS. The exception is thrown on System.Console.IsOutputRedirected which can be omitted using configuration flags:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo
.Console(theme: Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.ConsoleTheme.None, applyThemeToRedirectedOutput: true)
```